# mysql trigger after update column from another table

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, database-trigger

I have 2 tables which are below.

I would like to create a trigger for table_one. when changed the username in table_one, update user_id value from the table_two user value.

```
table_one:
+--------------+----------+
| user_id      | username |
+--------------+----------+
| 15           | robin    |
| 46           | albert   |
+--------------+----------+
```

```
table_two:
+--------------+----------+
| id           | user     |
+--------------+----------+
| 1            | john     |
| 2            | jack     |
| 3            | robin    |
| 4            | kylie    |
| 5            | robert   |
| 6            | albert   |
| 7            | jay      |
+--------------+----------+
```

thanks in advance

Comment: are the users in table1 also in table2?

Comment: yes. table_two is the main table for users. table_one is just taking the log.

Comment: So table2 is a change log?

Comment: no table2 for log. table1 is user table.

Comment: Sorry, misread that. So If I change user 15 to John, should that insert a new record into Table1? Therefore table1 would have two records of ID15 - Robin and John?

Comment: for example, when change "robin" in table_one, go to table_two and find "robin" id value in table_two. and after that, update the "user_id" in table_one

Comment: I'm not sure doing that makes sense in most designs, which means you may have a problem with your design, but if you wanted to do it I believe it would need to be in a **BEFORE** UPDATE query; and you'd `SET NEW.user_id = ` rather than execute another UPDATE query from within the trigger.

Comment: What if username is updated to a name not in table 2?

Comment: it is not possible. because I controlled the which username can changeable in table1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, not an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

(I don't think it's possible in an AFTER UPDATE trigger to modify the row that was updated, that fired the trigger. I could be wrong about that, but I just can't wrap my brain around how that would work.)

This is a demonstration of a BEFORE UPDATE trigger on `table_one` that assigns a value to the `user_id` column (of the row being updated) based on the result from a query:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ... 
BEFORE UPDATE ON table_one
BEGIN

  # local variable we will temporarily store a value fetched from a query
  DECLARE li_new_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;  # match datatype of table_two.id

  # lookup `id` value from `table_two` with a SQL query
  SELECT s.id
    INTO li_new_id
    FROM table_two s
   WHERE s.user = NEW.username
   ORDER BY s.id 
   LIMIT 1 ;

  # assign the value we fetched to the `user_id` column of the row being updated
  SET NEW.user_id := li_new_id ;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that if the query doesn't find a matching row, the local variable will have a NULL value. So the SET statement will assign NULL to to the `user_id` column. There's no check in the trigger that the value we assign won't violate a constraint (NOT NULL, UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY).

Comment: Correct - you can't change the values in `NEW.*` in an AFTER trigger.

Comment: @spencer7593

also is this code work?

`
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger 
BEFORE UPDATE ON wpescq_policeler
BEGIN

  
  SET NEW.user_id = (SELECT s.id AS li_new_id FROM table_two s WHERE s.user = NEW.username ORDER BY s.id LIMIT 1)

END$$

DELIMITER ;
`

Comment: I used a local variable to be able to break up the two steps ... fetching a value from a query, and assigning a value to a column. To me, it makes sense to do it as two separate steps. In the future, there might be some other verification we want to do on the fetched value, executing other queries.  I know when I come back to maintain the trigger, I'm going to appreciate that the two operations are being performed in two separate statements.